# Pandas - get column position based on another dataframe series

Tags: pandas, python-2.7

I need to get column position in dataframe 1 based on value in column name extracted from dataframe 2. In example I am showing column position in df1 is '0' and it's name is 'Customer_Number'. In df2 there is column 'Headers' with value 'Customer_Number'.
I am using 'df.columns.get_loc' and it works OK if I pass exact column Name:

```
df1.columns.get_loc('Customer_Number')
```

Result: 0

But If I pass as a column name object from df2 ('df2.Headers' returns only one value i.e. 'Customer_Number') it rises an error:

```
df1.columns.get_loc(df2.Headers)
```

Result: *TypeError: '635    Customer_Number
Name: Headers, dtype: object' is an invalid key*

I have tried to convert object type to string but the error remains the same:

```
df1.columns.get_loc(df2.Headers.astype('str'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found workaround for this. First, I have converted row from dataframe 2 into  a list (actually list of lists) using `map(list, df.values)`, and then extracted from this list (by position, as it will always be fixed) value corresponding to 'Customer_Number' and pass it as argument for `get_loc`

Though this solved my problem, I would gladly accept more elegant solution as an answer.